# T-SQL : use an array like in a while loop

Tags: sql, arrays, t-sql, while-loop, do-while

I want to loop a array of chars in a WHILE loop (with only two values : 'C' & 'P') and use this variable in a SQL statement.

PSEUDO CODE:

```
WHILE SELECT 'C' UNION SELECT 'P'
BEGIN
    SELECT @Var -- Do real sql-statement here
END
```

I've this working code, but I was wondering if this can be written better / easier / more elegantly ?

```
DECLARE @Var CHAR(1)
DECLARE @counter INT
SET @counter = 0
WHILE @counter < 2
BEGIN
  SELECT @Var = 
    CASE @counter
        WHEN 0 THEN 'C'
        ELSE 'P'
    END

  SELECT @Var -- Do real sql-statement here
  SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
```

To clarify, the real sql-statement is something like:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
    SELECT A, B, @Var FROM AnotherTable WHERE ExportStatus = 'F'
```

Comment: It really does depend on the `real sql` that you are trying to do.  Generally you should be able to avoid loops, but not always.  If this really does require a loop, what you have is fine.  Or, you could consider a `FAST_FORWARD READONLY Cursor` and loop through your input data with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
    SELECT * FROM AnotherTable WHERE ExportStatus 
        IN (SELECT 'C' UNION ALL SELECT 'P')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just insert it into the table.

Set operation perform better in SQL
and A array can be placed into a table and operation can be performed on the table.